# Significance test on likelihood ratio of two completely specified models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Suppose that I collect some dataset $Y$ which is a sample from a  multinomial distribution with unknown event probabilities $\theta_{truth}=(p_1,p_2,...,p_k)$ where $\sum{p}=1$.

I have two competing models which each use theory to make a prediction about the true event probabilities $\theta_{truth}$:

$$
Model 1: \theta = \theta_1 = (a_1,a_2,...,a_k)\\
Model 2: \theta = \theta_2 = (b_1,b_2,...,b_k)\\
\sum{a}=1\\
\sum{b}=1
$$

Consider the relative likelihood that $Y$ was drawn from a multinomial distribution parameterized by $\theta_2$ vs $\theta_1$:

$$
\Lambda=\frac{\mathscr{L}(Y|\theta_2)}{\mathscr{L}(Y|\theta_1)}
$$

I would like to test the hypothesis that this likelihood ratio is greater than 1; i.e. I want a significance test on $H_0:\Lambda\leq1$, $H_1:\Lambda>1$. Since my models are not nested (they both have zero free parameters), I don't think (?) I can use Wilk's Theorem to help.

I could bootstrap samples from $Y$ and use this to get a 95% confidence interval on $\Lambda$ (and thus see whether the 95% CI crosses 1 and such). But, is there a more "classical" way to do this that doesn't require resampling?

Comment: The likelihood ratio $\Lambda$ is calculated from the data, so when you have $Y$, it is a known value, it is not an unknown parameter.  So your hypothesis as formulated does not make sense. Please rethink!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Maybe I am not clear above. $Y$ is a sample from a multinomial distribution with some parameters $\theta$. If I draw another sample of size $|Y|$ from the same population, the value of $\Lambda$ will change. I am trying to test the hypothesis that given my sample $Y$, Model 2 is a better predictor of the expected proportions for *any* sample I take from that population. I realize my notation in my question was a bit inconsistent, it's edited now - does that make it clearer?

Comment: This still is difficult to decipher.  Are you, or are you not, testing hypotheses about the parameters?  What does it really mean to have "two competing models"?  Are there any unknown parameters involved?  If you're just comparing two specific probability distributions, all you can do is determine which one yields the greater of the two likelihoods. There's nothing else to test.  What would be the point of bootstrapping, since you claim that some kind of theory has pinned down the parameters to one of two values?

Comment: @whuber Suppose I flip a coin 10 times and get 7 heads, and I want to compare the models $M_1: p(H)=0.5$ and $M_2: p(H)=0.6$. Here $\Lambda \approx 1.8$. It seems to me that I should be able to put a confidence interval on $\Lambda$, akin to asking "If I were take this same coin and repeatedly flip it 10 times and calculate $\Lambda$ each time, what range of $\Lambda$ should I expect to see?" It further seems to me that if this 95% confidence interval does not include $\Lambda=1$, this is akin to saying that Model 2 is significantly better than Model 1. Is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: That's called a *prediction interval.*  The only meaningful confidence sets in this setup would be $\emptyset,$ $\{0.5\},$ $\{0.6\},$ and $\{0.5,0.6\}.$  A confidence set would be a function assigning one member of this collection to each possible sample.  With such a simple, artificial setup most of the procedures and theorems you might know don't apply and it's best to work out useful confidence intervals from definitions and basic principles.

Comment: @whuber A more general question, then: how would a frequentist put a p-value on the claim that, given the data I've observed, $M_2$ is a significantly better model of my coin than $M_1$?

Comment: Apply the definition.  That's straightforward to do when the null hypothesis is "simple," which means it consists of a unique distribution (rather than a family of them).

Comment: @whuber Would it look like this? $M_2$ outperforms $M_1$ when the proportion of heads I observe $P(H)_{obs}>(0.5+0.6)/2$, so when $P(H)_{obs}>0.55$. So, the p-value I want given that I observe 7/10 heads is $P(H_{obs}=7/10 | P(H) \leq 0.55)$, so $p \approx 0.27$. So, my question reduces to a one-sided binomial test with the null value of $P(H)$ set to the point above which $M_2$ starts to outperform $M_1$. Is this correct? If so, I'm completely lost about how I could generalize this logic to the multinomial problem above.